# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, 64 bit, 386 architecture

Tags: 12.04, usb, 64-bit

What I have:

1)  128 GB USB drive

2)  Dell Laptop with Windows 7, 8 GB memory, Intel i7-3540M

What I want:

3)  Bootable USB drive with Ubuntu 12.04 for that hardware configuration, with GUI, with most of that drive available persistently.

My preferred method:

4)  Something like Universal USB installer, to put an image of a 64 bit desktop version of Ubuntu 12.04 on, and then do the gparted/casper-rw partition re-sizing.

I cannot find such a thing.  On [the releases page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) I see 64 bit desktop for AMD, or 32 bit desktop for i386.  Am I looking for something which does not exist?

(Why I want it:  I am desperately trying to get cross-compilation support for a new Jetson Nvidia card, and I am led to believe that Nvidia does not support cross compilation **from** anything more recent than 12.04... which is baffling, since the card itself comes with 14.04, but if my statement is out of date I cannot find any evidence of it.  I'm sure this will be the topic of an upcoming question.)

Comment: AMD64 is not for AMD ))

Comment: Are you saying that AMD64 will work for this hardware?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Aha.  Thanks, I will try it out and report back.

Comment: This worked.  If you convert your comment to an answer, I will happily accept it.  Now, of course, the initial apt-get update and install are failing, but that is a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD64 image is not for AMD CPUs, but exactly what you need.
64-bit image that will work on Core i7.